# Need Suggestions: Utilizing columnar database

Tags: database, nosql

I am working on a project which is highly performance dashboard where results are mostly aggregated mixed with non-aggregated data. First page is loaded by 8 different complex queries, getting mixed data. Dashboard is served by a centralized database (Oracle 11g) which is receiving data from many systems in realtime ( using replication tool). Data which is shown is realized through very complex queries ( multiple `join`, `count`, `group by` and many `where` conditions).

The issue is that as data is increasing, DB queries are taking more time than defined/agreed. I am thinking to move aggregated functionality to Columnar database say `HBase` ( all the counts), and rest linear data will be fetched from Oracle. Both the data will be merged based on a key on App layer. Need experts opinion if this is correct approach.

There are few things which are not clear to me:
1. Will `Sqoop` be able to load data based on query/view or only tables? on continuous basis or one time?
2. If a record is modified ( e.g. status is changed), how will `HBase` get to know?

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. HBase is a NoSQL database build for fast lookup queries, not to make aggregated, ad-hoc queries.

If you are planning to use a hadoop cluster, you can try hive with parquet storage formart. If you need near real-time queries, you can go with MPP database. A commercial option is Vertica or maybe Redshift from Amazon. For an open-source solution, you can use InfoBrigth.

These columnar options is going to give you a greate aggregate query performance.